# How to show bootstrap tooltip title from variable in Thymeleaf?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Is there any way to show bootstrap tooltip title from variables in thymeleaf? Bootstrap tooltip static title in thymeleaf is:

```
<td th:text="${user.firstName}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Lastname: Lopez" />
```

I am looking something similar to

```
<td th:text="${user.firstName}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" th:title="'Lastname: ' + ${user.lastName}" />
```

Comment: `th:title` should work. Have you tried it?

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`th:title` is the correct way. See https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#setting-value-to-specific-attributes for a list of all possible attributes.